# Button dropdown does not scale in fluid grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We use bootstrap 2 button dropdown in fluid grid, and because the label of button dropdown is kind of long.

We would like this button *more responsive* like normal button in narrow screen. Example below: the first button is button dropdown and the second is normal button. The second is scaled as expected but the first is not.

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="btn-group"> 
                <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Download Rate Letter word1 word2 word3 word4
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li> <a href="#">PDF Format</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Excel Format</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Download Rate Letter word1 word2 word3 word4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to work around?

[jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/35fcA/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer not customizing bootstrap with `btn-group-justify`:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justify">
....
</div>
```

jsFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/35fcA/5/

Answer (score 2):

This is because .btn-group has `white-space: nowrap`, which means that content will never "break" onto the next line.

You need to add this to your CSS.

```
.btn-group {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35fcA/2/

Answer (score 0):

Michelle is right. `white-space: nowrap` is the issue. Needs to be changed to `white-space: normal` like she said. But then the issue is going to be the height. Basically, when the word runs to the second line, like it is supposed to, then one button will be taller than the rest. This wouldn't be an issue, but you may have a border you are trying to achieve on the buttons, or a changing background on hover. This is when it will be an issue that they are not the same height.

In this case, I think it would be best to add additional CSS that increases the heights to be equal or add JavaScript/JQuery to automatically get the height of the tallest button and make all the buttons the same height, on window load and resize. Neither are the greatest option because it is hard to make the CSS responsive and not all users have JavaScript enabled etc.

I am looking for the same solution. I also am trying table styling, instead of the justified button group Bootstrap 3 offers. I am using Roots theme (roots.io). I think as long as you can find something that will work down to 330px you will be okay.

Probably what would be best is to use are responsive data tables:

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Then try to style to fill container width and be equal height, until it can't fit nicely width wise, wherein it then changes to be a different style menu. Issue with tables, is it has to be a table because display:table* don't work in IE8 and older etc. Tables are hard to redesign with @media queries even though you can get @media queries to work on IE8 and older, but WITH JavaScript, again, not all users using JavaScript. Ultimatel

Ultimately, you are not asking a small question. You are really asking "How do I make a multiple divs, fill a container, and be equal height, regardless of whether the number of divs increases or descreases ?" <-- which is a HUGE question when it comes to IE8 and older and people with JavaScript disabled etc.

MY IDEA:
 1. I would make people with JavaScript turned off have a fixed width. This is tough because of mobile devices and how they will behave for scaling the browser. So, you have to set a minimum width on what wraps your content, then turn it off with javascript. 
 2. Design the site to look fine with CSS at your min width for non Javascript users. You can do this by disabling Javascript, viewing the site at the minimum width for no JS and designing accordingly. Then fix design with @media queries and JS. 
 3. Enable @media queries for IE8 and older (and older FireFox etc) with JS like cssmediaqueries.js or respond.js etc.

That way, if there is no javascript, there will be no need for @media queries and the site will be styled to look fine without it, that will be the bare minimum design. THEN you should be able to get everything to look pretty much perfect across all browsers including older browsers, with the help of @media queries and javascript.

FOR YOUR PROJECT:

I will let you know. I still think working with tables for responsive width and height is going to be the best option - either that or figure out a way to make the buttons equal height some other way.